# create Dynamic HTML Element In JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var vStatus = "welcome";
var val  = '';
var fContactInfo = new Array();
fContactInfo.push('<div class="readText"> <div class="leftText">123</div><div class="middleText">'+ if(vStatus != ""){ +'<div>Sent'+vStatus+'</div>'+} if(val! = ''){ +'<div>Submitted '+val+'</div>'+}+'</div> <div class="rightText"></div></div>');

$('#A1').html(fContactInfo.join(' '));
```

**

> http://jsfiddle.net/JaqfH/

**

Hello Everyone,

I am trying to create new html element here but the value which i give are conditional. when try the above code it gives me error. can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: As a first step, I would build that BIG string in several statements, not all at once. It will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax errors in your code.

Corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/vGcT8/1/

You can't add `strings` and `if` expressions.